# Neo4j Can you select colors, sizes for nodes and relationships in your match(n) return n statement?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have created nodes and relationships in neo4j.  I can return all by using `match (n) return n` and then change the colors and sizes of nodes/relationships by clicking on buttons in the browser.

Can you define this in your match and return query before the visualization is displayed?

Comment: https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The presentation and visualization has nothing to do with the database or the executed Cypher, that's defined solely in the application used to perform the visualization.